# Excluding matplotlib backends from py2app

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, py2app

I'm using `py2app` to make a `wxPython` frozen binary that uses `matplotlib` (whew).  The resulting executable is quite large, so I'd like to whittle it down if possible.

One obvious way of doing this is to exclude unneeded `matplotlib` backends.  I've tried running my script with `python setup.py py2app --matplotlib-backends -` which should compile only backends that are used in the script, as documented here: https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/options.html.  The resulting executable is indeed a lot smaller, but it's broken.  I also tried `python setup.py py2app --matplotlib-backends "WXAgg"` which failed the same way.  Here is most of the traceback (awkwardly copied from Console, sorry).

```
import wx

File "wx/__init__.pyc", line 45, in <module>

File "wx/_core.pyc", line 4, in <module>

File "wx/_core_.pyc", line 14, in <module>

File "wx/_core_.pyc", line 10, in __load

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/***/***/***/dist/magic_gui.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/wx/_core_.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/***/***/***/dist/magic_gui.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/wx/_core_.so

Reason: image not found
```

Maybe I can explicitly tell it to include libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.dylib.  Or, maybe I need to explicitly include another backend (although I am using `wxPython`, so the WXAgg backend should be right).

I have two questions: first, is there a way I can include only required `matplotlib` backends without breaking my program?  Second, are there other ways I could/should consider to make my program smaller with py2app?